# Starting with avx, why is it not faster?

Tags: intrinsics, avx, avx2

I'm trying to optimize the following function, using AVX. I did similar optimization using _m256i and I have a 10x faster function, but here, I have more or less the same process time.
Here is the original function :

```
    void setConv(int idx,double* kernel,int kWidth)
    {
        double kernel0 = kernel[0];
            if (!r || !g || !b) return;

        double sumrX = r[idx] * kernel0;
        double sumrY = r[idx] * kernel0;
        double sumgX = g[idx] * kernel0;
        double sumgY = g[idx] * kernel0;
        double sumbX = b[idx] * kernel0;
        double sumbY = b[idx] * kernel0;

        for (int ri = 1; ri < kWidth; ri++)
        {
            double kernelri = kernel[ri];
            int ri_nc = ri*_nc;
            sumrY += kernelri * (r[idx - ri_nc] + r[idx + ri_nc]);
            sumrX += kernelri * (r[idx - ri] + r[idx + ri]);
            sumgY += kernelri * (g[idx - ri_nc] + g[idx + ri_nc]);
            sumgX += kernelri * (g[idx - ri] + g[idx + ri]);
            sumbY += kernelri * (b[idx - ri_nc] + b[idx + ri_nc]);
            sumbX += kernelri * (b[idx - ri] + b[idx + ri]);
        }
        yrConv[idx] = sumrY;
        xrConv[idx] = sumrX;
        ygConv[idx] = sumgY;
        xgConv[idx] = sumgX;
        ybConv[idx] = sumbY;
        xbConv[idx] = sumbX;
    }
```

and here is the AVX one
__m256d* sumY; <-- allocated somewhere else
__m256d* sumX; <-- to replace xxConv array

```
   void setConv(int idx, double* kernel, int kWidth)
   {
      if (!r || !g || !b) return;

      __m256d sumrgb = _mm256_setr_pd(r[idx], g[idx], b[idx], 0);
      __m256d kernel0 = _mm256_set1_pd(kernel[0]);
      
      sumX[idx] = _mm256_mul_pd(sumrgb, kernel0);
      sumY[idx] = sumX[idx];

      for (int ri = 1; ri < kWidth; ri++)
      {
         __m256d kernelri = _mm256_set1_pd(kernel[ri]);

         int ri_nc = ri * _nc;

         __m256d sumrgb1 = _mm256_setr_pd(r[idx - ri], g[idx - ri], b[idx - ri], 0);
         __m256d sumrgb2 = _mm256_setr_pd(r[idx + ri], g[idx + ri], b[idx + ri], 0);
         __m256d sumrgbX = _mm256_add_pd(sumrgb1, sumrgb2);

         sumX[idx] = _mm256_fmadd_pd(kernelri, sumrgbX, sumX[idx]);

         sumrgb1 = _mm256_setr_pd(r[idx - ri_nc], g[idx - ri_nc], b[idx - ri_nc], 0);
         sumrgb2 = _mm256_setr_pd(r[idx + ri_nc], g[idx + ri_nc], b[idx + ri_nc], 0);
         __m256d sumrgbY = _mm256_add_pd(sumrgb1, sumrgb2);

         sumY[idx] = _mm256_fmadd_pd(kernelri, sumrgbY, sumY[idx]);
      }
   }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a best way to do that?

Comment: `_mm256_setr_pd`is not fast with multiple runtime-variable operands.  It costs a lot of shuffles to do all the interleaving.  If you can store your results in a more convenient format like the scalar version, you could do four `sumrX` elements in one vector, and four `sumrY` in another, no shuffling needed (just unaligned loads), In fact the compiler might already be auto-vectorizing your scalar code, especially if `kWidth` is a small compile-time constant.  But even if not, maybe.

Comment: Each element needs a different distance (`+ri` vs. `-ri`) in the source arrays if you try to vectorize over `ri`, but then you'd also need a horizontal sum.  Ideally you can vectorize over `idx` so you can simply use two contiguous loads fixed distances from each other so every vector element is for a different `idx`.  Or if you used `vpermpd` to reverse the order of one vector, you could get vectors with increasing distance in either direction away from an `idx`.

Comment: Compiler says the loop is not vectorized, because of the +ri -ri.
And I'm not sure to understand what you say about the four elements ?